# Why does the expanded nested GridView automatically closes after opening it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have the following GridView inside an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExpCol" ImageUrl="~/theImages/subTaskPlus.png" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgExpCol" AlternateText="plus" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") %>' OnCommand="imgExpCol_Command" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubTasks" runat="server" CssClass="pnlSubTasks" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSubTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Task Name" HeaderText="Task Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/theImages/Dependencies.png" CssClass="gvTaskDep btnShowDepend" runat="server" ID="btnShowDepend" OnCommand="btnShowDepend_Command" CommandName="TaskDepend" AlternateText='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' ToolTip="Click to view Dependencies" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Site" HeaderText="Site" SortExpression="Site" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Practice" HeaderText="Practice" SortExpression="Practice" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Provider" HeaderText="Provider" SortExpression="Provider" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Roles" HeaderText="Roles" SortExpression="Roles" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Object" HeaderText="Object" SortExpression="Object" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideTag" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideTag" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FK" HeaderText="FK" SortExpression="Object" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideTag" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideTag" />
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', "input[alt='plus']", function () {
        alert("test");
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskMinus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "minus");
    });
    $("body").on('click', "input[alt='minus']", function () {
        alert("test2");
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskPlus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "plus");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
});
```

code-behind:

```
protected void yourTasksGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvSubTasks") as GridView;
        gvOrders.DataSource = RunSubTaskQuery();
        gvOrders.DataBind();

        TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

        //BEGIN: FIGURE OUT WHICH ROW SHOULD HAVE THE PLUS ICON
        #region
        List<string> lstSubTask = new List<string>();

        string strQuerySubTasks = @"SELECT 
                CT.OBJECTID 'Object ID'
                ,ATTR2888 'Subtask Name'
                ,M.MEMO 'Subtask Details'
                ,ATTR2890 'Status'
                ,ST.FK2898 'Parent Task Object ID'
                ,CT.ATTR2739 'Parent Task Name'
            FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1244 ST
                INNER JOIN HSI.RMMEMO M ON ST.MK2889 = M.MEMOID
                INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT ON ST.FK2898 = CT.OBJECTID
            WHERE ST.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.OBJECTID = '" + objectid + "'";

        using (SqlConnection scSubTask = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuerySubTasks, scSubTask);
            scSubTask.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdrST = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objectid) && objectid != "&nbsp;")
            {
                while (sdrST.Read())
                {
                    lstSubTask.Add(sdrST[0].ToString().TrimEnd());
                }
            }

            sdrST.Close();
        }
        #endregion
        if (lstSubTask.Count == 0)
        {
            ImageButton ibExp = e.Row.FindControl("imgExpCol") as ImageButton;
            if (ibExp != null)
            {
                ibExp.Visible = false;
            }
            //hide the plus button
        }//END: FIGURE OUT WHICH ROW SHOULD HAVE THE PLUS ICON
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is, when I click the plus button to expand the existing row to show the nested GridView, it opens but collapses by itself after a few seconds and doesn't wait for me to close it manually.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Since you're not showing the relevant HTML, we can only guess.  When you debug this in the browser, is the click handler you created with jQuery invoked at all?  If so, where does it fail?  If not, then the selector likely isn't matching the element.

Comment: I modified the code/question to ask the real issue I am having. Sorry about that.

Comment: I see that you're having `OnCommand="btnShowDepend_Command" CommandName="TaskDepend" ... ` for the `ImageButton` which you are using for expand/collapse using jquery, What do you do in the code behind for that command?

Comment: What causes it to collapse?  The JavaScript code?  A post-back to the server that resets its state?  Please describe the specific behavior you observe when you debug this.

Comment: @DennisR That's for a different function.

Comment: I had to add `return false;` and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskPlus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskMinus.png"");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

I am using the above javascript to expand and collapse my gridviews within gridviews. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: I think `LIVE` has been depreceted :/

Comment: I remove the second part and it is still doing it. So I think it is not the JQuery which is causing the issue but rather the state of the GridView. It is somehow refreshing with the `RowDataBound`

Comment: I had to `return FALSE;` in the onclick method, because it is a input type, it acts as a submit button.